# How to run jquery only one time

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to run a jquery function only one time when the page is loaded first time. It means when i load the page again jquery function should not run.

example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).load(function(){
     alert(hello);
 });
});
```

please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: So only once ever per person/browser viewing the page?

Comment: yes only once per person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that you'd need to set some storage/persistence

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!localStorage.getItem('loaded')) {
        alert(hello);
        localStorage.setItem('loaded', 'done');
    }
});
```

The above checks for a record in `localStorage`, and sets if not already

One thing to note with both local and session storage is that values are stored as strings, so be careful if setting values to true/false as they wont be Boolean on retrieval.

Comment: Very little risk in using localStorage nowadays, do check the known issues on http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage though.
Also like to point out wrapping a window.load in a doc.rdy is a bit redundant, the window object is always available, event before the document is ready.

Comment: yeah, no one uses opera mini anyway

Comment: is it the safest and most reliable way ?

Comment: there isn't really anything unsafe or unreliable about it. it's supported by pretty much everything. using javascript for this isnt a great solution and really it should be managed on the server, but if you want a js solution this is pretty solid

Comment: is there any server side solution? How can i achieve that solution? can u give me an example please

Comment: there are many server side solutions. please update your questions with details of the server side set up. You'd also be better of explaining exactly what you want to do in the jquery code only once.

Answer (score 0):

super easy HTML5 approach: (not suitable for older browsers)

```
$(function(){
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("ran") != "true") {
        //your running once code here.
        window.localStorage.setItem("ran", "true");
    }
})
```

The code code simply try to get the field "ran" via the local storage from HTML5, which is supported by modern browsers.

If you would like to support older browsers, translate this into a cookie format, like this:

```
$(function(){
    if(document.cookie != "ran=true") {
        //your running once code here.
        document.cookie = "ran=true";
    }
})
```

Comment: @user3456241 ok, please wait

Comment: doing `document.cookie = "something"` will only prepend "something" to the existing cookie not replace it. so `document.cookie` will never `==` "something"